# Substituting maseca (corn flour) for ap flour in waffle cones

Tags: baking, substitutions, molecular-gastronomy, waffle, vital-wheat-gluten

I want to make a maseca based waffle cone but I am not sure what to use as the binding agent in substitute of flour. My first assumption was to mix in a .7% ratio of vital wheat gluten. Any suggestions on binders/stabilizers? The end product will be served warm around 52-55c (120-130f). Ideally I would like it to have the same crunch as a standard cone but with the corn flavour. The sweetness is not an issue but because the overall dish will be savoury I hope to have it no sweeter than a basic cone is now.

Comment: +1 for creativity.  Have you tried just replacing the flour with the maseca?  What happens?  Also, what is your goal?  Is this for flavor?

Comment: Most corn bread recipes are a combination of both AP flour and corn flour... have you tried a mixture of them?

Comment: Maseca is not strictly corn flour, rather it is instant masa...that is, the corn has been nixtamalized before being dried and ground.

Comment: the end product will be a savory dish that looks like and ice cream cone with whip cream, sprinkles and a cherry on top, but turkey mole theme. Plantain-coconut milk hot sponge ice cream, turkey and epazote espuma whipped cream, chipotle pickled mexican cucumber, pepitas-sesame granola sprinkle, and a mole ganache dipped around the masa waffle cone. My first try was similar to a conbread/waffle cone hybrid spec and didn't work, there was no structure. I used a 90/10 ratio of maseca/ap. my kitchen has been too busy for me to have my mad scientist play time to do proper testing